# Download content from a webpage using wget

Tags: wget, archive

I would like to download all the books from the gutenberg project using wget.
I want to get them in the epub format.
The link to the list is:
[http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=epub.images&langs[]=fr](http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes%5B%5D=epub.images&langs%5B%5D=fr)
but when i run:

```
  wget -H -w 2 -m "http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest?filetypes[]=epub.images&langs[]=fr"
```

It downloads the html page not all the files linked in the page.
Hope this is clear enough.
It is inspired from this question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12311/how-to-download-all-english-books-from-gutenberg

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right. It's Gutenberg's servers that are broken (temporarily, I hope).

What happens is: the pages you're fetching link to EPUB files under  aleph.gutenberg.org/cache/, but aleph.gutenberg.org disallows robot access to the /cache. That's why Wget skips all the EPUB files.

I wrote an email to Project Gutenberg, and I hope they'll fix this soon — their contact page promises answers within two days. Just try again in a few days. (Or find a way to work around robots.txt. I don't want to publish it here because most of the time people misuse it to do bad stuff.)

Update November 29th: the problem have been fixed.